# combine columns with factors (Levels: 0= as no; 1 = as yes)

Tags: r

I have dumb question to ask. I am trying to combine two columns with factors to make it as a single column.

levels (0 and 1) are like no and yes.

So if I combine 1 and 1 it should give me 1; 0 and 1 as 1 etc...

Thanks for any info...
murali

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

> head(testmerge$glucosystemic,10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1 glucosystemic
> head(testmerge$glucolocal,10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
Levels: 0 1 glucolocal
> str(testmerge$glucosystemic)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","glucosystemic": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str(testmerge$glucolocal)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","glucolocal": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
```

This solved the question

```
### from stackflow help
glucomerge <- function(vec1, vec2) {as.numeric(as.numeric(vec1) + as.numeric(vec2) > 2)}
testmerge$glucoco <- glucomerge(testmerge$glucosystemic,testmerge$glucolocal)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your "etc" it's not fully clear, but it looks like the OR operator. Can you confirm?

Comment: so if i combine one column (0,1) with another(1,1). it should give (1,1) respectively.

Comment: Your factors have three levels, not only `"0"` and `"1"`. What happens with the levels `"glucosystemic"` and `"glucolocal"`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following:

```
as.numeric(as.numeric(vec1) + as.numeric(vec2) > 2)
```

---

You can wrap it in a nice function, where you simply run:

```
 FactorOR(testmerge[, c("glucosystemic", "glucolocal")])
 #  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1


# Where the function is defined as: 
FactorOR <- function(TwoColDF) {
    as.numeric(as.numeric(TwoColDF[,1]) + as.numeric(TwoColDF[,2]) > 2)
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped.  However, I like @Henrik 's solution a lot more

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
x3 <- ifelse(x1 == 1 | x2 == 1, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is testmerge, you can use `interaction` for that.

`testmerge$col<-with(testmerge, interaction (glucosystemic,glucolocal))`

Updated: You can use as.numeric to assign the level.

```
testmerge$col<-with(testmerge, as.numeric(interaction (glucosystemic,glucolocal)))
```

Comment: many thanks,, but when i try to do it with the interaction, the third column is with the values of both the column                              
 0 and 1 gave 0.1